# When opening IntelliJ's Scenebuilder with a browserview in it. I can't run/debug the app because the BrowserContext is locked

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I'm getting the

> Chromium profile directory is already used/locked by another BrowserContext instance or process

error when I try to debug/run the app after opening the scene builder to edit the fxml in IntelliJ.

Only solution i have is to restart IntelliJ and don't touch the scene builder and the app can be debugged/run.

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `The Chromium profile directory is already used/locked by another BrowserContext instance or process` error message indicates that you've faced concurrent access to the Chromium data folder.
Please take a look at the following article which explains the root cause of this issue and possible ways to resolve it: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012878-creating-browser

EDIT____________________________________________

The error means that 2 browsercore processes are trying to get access to the same user data folder at the same time. You can check it in the Task Manager. In order to get rid of this error, please make sure that there are no browsercore processes running when you launch the Scene Builder.

Comment: doesn't help. I just copied the FXML part in this guide https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013071-using-jxbrowser-in-javafx and modified the fxml in scene builder. 

Again, this works IF I DON'T TOUCH IntelliJ's SCENE BUILDER. Restarting IntelliJ and not touching Scene builder allows me to run/debug properly. After opening the scene builder, then I get that error

Comment: you're right. IntelliJ doesn't kill browsercore processes when I switch away to the scene builder. If you can edit your answer to that, I'll mark that as the answer. Thanks for the help!